# Increase size of EC2 volume (non-root) on Ubuntu 18.04 (following AWS instructions fail)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

There is a ton of great information on here, but I am struggling with this, I am following instructions EXACTLY as laid out in many responses, AND on AWS's instructions as well, which are basically the same with a lot of extra information in between, however unhelpful.

Here is what I am running and the responses I am getting. I have a secondary volume that I need to expand from 150GB to 200GB.

The thing is before the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 this process worked flawlessly... Now, it doesnt.

Please help.

````
ubuntu@hosting:~$ df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  848K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1 ext4       97G   55G   43G  57% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G   20K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M   24K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme2n1p1 ext4      148G   91G   51G  64% /var/www/vhosts
/dev/nvme1n1   ext4       99G   28G   67G  30% /plesk-backups
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/10046

ubuntu@hosting:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme2n1     259:0    0  200G  0 disk
└─nvme2n1p1 259:1    0  150G  0 part /var/www/vhosts
nvme1n1     259:2    0  100G  0 disk /plesk-backups
nvme0n1     259:3    0  100G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1 259:4    0  100G  0 part /

ubuntu@hosting:~$ sudo growpart /dev/nvme2n1 1
NOCHANGE: partition 1 is size 419428319. it cannot be grown

ubuntu@hosting:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme2n1p1
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
The filesystem is already 39321339 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!```
````

Comment: Have you tried using fdisk?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `cfdisk` tool by sudo user `sudo cfdisk`, and then allocate the free space to the partition you want to expand on the popup UI (don't forget to write to disk before quite the tool), then run `resize2fs` again.